# SQL Server : Didn't understand why I can update stat with column/index on the same statistic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to read stored procedure to update statistic in my company have 2 commands for update statistic for each.

For example

```
stat name '_WA_Sys_00000002_0BC6C43E'
```

They have 2 commands for update stat

```
update statistics [dbo].[Table_1] [_WA_Sys_00000002_0BC6C43E] with columns
update statistics [dbo].[Table_1] [_WA_Sys_00000002_0BC6C43E] with index
```

I think this is a column stat. An the stat that create automatically when create index is a index stat.

I don't understand why they do 'update stat with index' for a column stat. And I amazing that it can ran with successfully for both command.

Do you have any idea? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what the question is. Can you show fuller code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the official docs when in doubt..

here is syntax for updating stats..

```
UPDATE STATISTICS table_or_indexed_view_name   
    [   
        {   
            { index_or_statistics__name }  
          | ( { index_or_statistics_name } [ ,...n ] )   
                }  
    ]   
    [    WITH   
        [  
            FULLSCAN   
            | SAMPLE number { PERCENT | ROWS }   
            | RESAMPLE   
              [ ON PARTITIONS ( { <partition_number> | <range> } [, …n] ) ]  
            | <update_stats_stream_option> [ ,...n ]  
        ]   
        [ [ , ] [ ALL | COLUMNS | INDEX ]   
        [ [ , ] NORECOMPUTE ]   
        [ [ , ] INCREMENTAL = { ON | OFF } ]  
    ] ;
```

Now taking the relevant part..

```
ALL | COLUMNS | INDEX
```

here is what MSDN has to say about this..

> Update all existing statistics, statistics created on one or more columns, or statistics created for indexes. If none of the options are specified, the UPDATE STATISTICS statement updates all statistics on the table or indexed view.

So when you specify columns ,you are only updating stats on columns ,when you specify indexes,you are updating only stats on index columns..

Generally  you can use below command which will update all stats on columns and indexes with default sampling..

> EXEC sp_updatestats;

Maintenance work like index rebuilds/stats update/any maintenance work  is done on weekends..So when you rebuild indexes and run update stats after rebuilding,you are doing double work and also countering the affect of full scan..

Normally when we run index rebuild,it rebuilds indexes and update stats on index columns with full scan,then we run `update stats`,it again rebuilds stats on index columns and table with default sample rate..,which should be avoided..This is [covered by Benjamin Nevarej here](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/07/rebuilding-indexes-vs-updating-statistics/)

In this case you can do below..

1.Run Index rebuild
2.Now run only update stats only for columns ..

```
UPDATE STATISTICS dbo.SalesOrderDetail WITH FULLSCAN, COLUMNS
```